# how to upload figma file(wireframe) on github?

Tags: github, design-patterns, mobile-application, wireframe, figma

I am making an app based on fitness. For that, I am making wireframe designs in Figma. Now I want to upload that Figma file on Github because I am working in a team of 4 members and we 4 can work together.

Answer (score 3):

[Figma Local Save File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BS12.png)

You can save a local Figma file (.fig) and share that with your team.

However, that would be counter-intuitive since Figma offers built-in collaborative editing on the same file.

This would be more efficient:

- Download Figma.
- Create New Team (left sidebar in home).
- Invite your members.
- Everyone on the team can now edit the file.